# vbscript not retrieving all server variables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic, vbscript, server-variables

I have a website that was written in VBSCRIPT that I am moving over to VB.NET.  Until I have time to get to rewriting some pages/applications, I would like to update some of the code so they work a bit better.  I am trying to grab a server variable on the VBSCRIPT page that contains our username from the enterprise login.

I have 2 test pages here, one with language="VB" at the top and the other language="VBSCRIPT".

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head runat="server">
           <title>Server Variables</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <form id="form1" runat="server">
               <div>
                   <%
                       For Each var In Request.ServerVariables
                           Response.Write("<b>" + var + "</b>= " + Request.ServerVariables(var) + "<br />")
                       Next
                   %>
               </div>
           </form>
       </body>
   </html>
```

The VBSCRIPT page will list variables with no data when they have data on the VB page and in ALL_HTTP.  Is there any way I can get VBSCRIPT to gather the correct info for all the server variables?

Thank You

EDIT:  These are the variables that vary between VB and VBS
AUTH_USER, REMOTE_USER - logged in user on VBS, iis_anon on VB
REMOTE_PORT - not listed in VBS

The following are listed in VBS, but have no data
HTTP_SERVER_PROTOCOL
HTTP_SM_TRANSACTIONID
HTTP_SM_CLIENT_IP
HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD
HTTP_SM_SDOMAIN
HTTP_SM_REALM
HTTP_SM_REALMOID
HTTP_SM_AUTHTYPE
HTTP_SM_AUTHREASON
HTTP_SM_UNIVERSALID
HTTP_SM_AUTHDIROID
HTTP_SM_AUTHDIRNAME
HTTP_SM_AUTHDIRSERVER
HTTP_SM_AUTHDIRNAMESPACE
HTTP_SM_USER
HTTP_SM_USERDN
HTTP_SM_SERVERSESSIONID
HTTP_SM_SERVERSESSIONSPEC
HTTP_SM_TIMETOEXPIRE
HTTP_SM_SERVERIDENTITYSPEC
HTTP_REMOTE_USER
Also there is a custom on I wish to get that is used for our enterprise authentication.

Comment: See this: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

Comment: Is it all variables that have no data, or only some variables?  Is there a way you could give us a sample (sanitized, if necessary)?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue before with custom HTTP headers that have underscores in the raw header name (which can be seen in the `ALL_RAW` server variable).  The `HTTP_` converts underscores to dashes (e.g., `HTTP_USER_AGENT` corresponds to an actual header called `User-Agent`).   In order to retrieve the values of any headers that have underscores in their names, you have to use the [`HEADER_`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28VS.90%29.aspx) prefix, which will search for the exact header name (e.g., `HEADER_USER_AGENT` will search for a header called `User_Agent`).

By the way, [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/04/20/howto-retrieve-request-headers-using-isapi-asp-and-asp-net.aspx) offers some more background information on why there are two prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

here a classic ASP page i have running on various IIS versions.
For the user, i have this in most of my projects which makes userinfo available on the server and client side. If you are on a domain replace DMAIN with yours, otherwise you can drop the replace.
NTLM security has to be enabled (windows authentication) on your IIS site, no anonymous access.
The list of servarvariables returned by this code is different depending on OS and IIS versions, enabled features, settings etc. Some keys will have empty values, so eg REMOTE_PORT is not avaiable on mine (i use the standard 80 port) but SERVER_PORT is.

```
<%
  Dim user
  user = Replace(uCase(Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")), "DOMAIN\", "")
%>
  <script type="text/javascript">var user = <%=user%></script>
```

Here the contents of servervariables.asp

```
<html>
<%@language=VBScript%>
<%
  With Response
    .Expires=-1
    .Clear
  End With
  dim teller
  response.write "<h1>Servervariables</h1>"
  response.write "<table>"
  teller = 1
  for each subkey in Request.Servervariables
    response.write "<tr><td>"
    response.write teller
    response.write "</td><td>"
    response.write (Request.Servervariables.Key(teller))
    response.write "</td><td>"
    response.write (Request.Servervariables.Item(teller))
    response.write "</td></tr>"
    teller = teller + 1 
  next
  response.write "</table>"
  response.write request.servervariables("path_translated") & "<br>"
  response.write "USER cookie:" & Request.Cookies("USER") & "<br>"
  response.write "USER Sessionvariable:" & Session("USER") & "<br>"
%>
</html>
```